# How to initiate a new Node.js file after already initiating some other Node.js file on Windows 10 machine?

Tags: javascript, node.js, windows, command-line-interface, command-prompt

I've a laptop running on **Windows 10 Home Single Language 64-bit Operating System**

I am learning **Node.js** on this machine.

For downloading and installing **Node.js** I went to the URL

`https://nodejs.org`.

From there I downloaded the **Node.js** setup file **v6.10.3 LTS for Windows (x64)**

I started installing **Node.js** by double-clicking on the setup file and keep on clicking the **Next** button in the installation wizard.

Then, I clicked on the Windows Start button(the button appearing in bottom-left corner of the screen), two new options were appeared in the list of **'Recently Added'** as **Node.js** and **'Node.js command prompt'**

I clicked on the option **'Node.js command prompt'**, then following screen appeared.
[image: Screen appeared after clicking on menu Node.js command prompt]

Then, I created one file titled `myfirst.js` at location

```
C:\Users\lenovo\myfirst.js
```

Then, I initiated this file by typing in following text at the command prompt I opened earlier :

```
C:\Users\lenovo>node myfirst.js
```

Then, I run the file `myfirst.js` from the browser by hitting the URL :

`http://localhost:8080/`

Till now everything worked fine for me.

But real problem started when I wanted to run another program.

For it do I need to close the command prompt by clicking on the close button icon appearing on the top-right corner of the window and should I need to do this before running any new **Node.js** program to initiate the respective file?

The screen I'm having problem with is appears as below with the name of earlier run Node.js program(i.e. with the last initiated Node.js file) :[image: Earlier Initiated Node.js file]

Someone please help me in this regard.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

So, I'm not on Windows, but in general each node application will run in a single process by default.  If you're running it from a command prompt, that will default to running the process in the foreground (meaning, it consumes the same process as your command window) and you have to open a new command window to run another program.  You can either close that first window, or run the node application in the background.

You'll also want to make sure you're not trying to do two programs listening on the same port (i.e. two node apps both running on port 8088), as that's also not possible.

Answer (score 1):

The node.js file you created is set up to listen to port 8080 and will do so until you "stop" the program from running.  To do this, press CTRL-C.  That will return you to the command prompt.  To run your next program, initiate it with node filename.js.